# Adding points at certain distances along lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, line

I have encountered the following problem: I have a set of lines in ArcMap. I need to place points at specified (not regular) distances along these lines. The distances are not the same between lines.

I feel its a waste of time to manually measure each distance and Place a Point there.

Any tips for a quicker way?

Comment: Have a look at the help file on linear referencing, if you have the distance and what line they are on in a table then it's fairly trivial.

Comment: http://ianbroad.com/arcgis-toolbox-create-points-polylines-arcpy/ this toolbox will create points along lines by percentage or a specified distance

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest looking into the linear referencing tools. This lets you define your lines as routes and create tables that will place events along these routes at specified measurements.

You should be able to make tables with the measurements you need to place points at, then create an event layer along your route with the points. These can then be exported to a separate featureclass if needed.

These articles should get you started:

Creating routes from lines - http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/linear-referencing/using-existing-linear-features-to-create-routes.htm

Create event table - http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/linear-referencing/about-creating-event-tables-in-arccatalog.htm

Display Events on route - http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/linear-referencing/adding-route-events-using-the-linear-referencing-toolbox.htm